# emberjs refreshing ArrayController with arrangedContent and @each crashes

Tags: ember.js

Hy and thanks for reading :

I have an issue with Ember.ArrayController and arrangedContent. The senario is as follow :

Items inside my arrayController can be modified by some actions.
My arrangedContent is filtred on some of those items properties.
Thus if an observed item property change the arrangedContent property should be refreshed

I achieve this by setting the `property()` of my arrangedContent with `"content.@each.myproperty"`

All works fine, except if i try to refresh the model from the route i then get an error message `TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined
    at ContainerView.extend.arrayWillChange`

In some case it would work but duplicate the content every time the refresh() is triggered

with some minimal code it may become more clear ...

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model : function(){
  return  [App.Cars.create({color : "red", model : "march"}),
           App.Cars.create({color : "yellow", model : "alto"}),
           App.Cars.create({color : "blue", model : "gundam"}) ];
  },
  actions : {
    reload : function(){
      this.refresh();
    }
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  arrangedContent  : function(){
    var data= this.get("content");
    data=data.filter(function(elem){
      return elem.get("color").match(new RegExp("el","gi"))!==null;
    });
    return data;
  }.property("lenght","content.@each.color"),
  actions : {
    allYell :function(){
      this.get("content").forEach(function(elem){
        elem.set("color","yellow");
      });
    },
    erase : function(){
      if(this.get("length")>0){
        this.get("content").removeAt(0);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

a JSBin can be found here http://jsbin.com/yebopobetu/3/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen anyone recommend overriding `arrangedContent`.  I honestly wouldn't recommend it.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  foos  : function(){
    var data= this.get("model");
    return data.filter(function(elem){
      return elem.get("color").match(new RegExp("el","gi"))!==null;
    });
  }.property("@each.color"),
  actions : {
    allYell :function(){
      this.forEach(function(elem){
        elem.set("color","yellow");
      });
    },
    erase : function(){
      if(this.get("length")>0){
        this.removeAt(0);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/sivugecunu/1/edit

Comment: Well from ember doc : _The array that the proxy pretends to be. In the default ArrayProxy implementation, this and content are the same. Subclasses of ArrayProxy can override this property to provide things like sorting and filtering._

Comment: And it is overridden in the sortable mixin, where it doesn't mention that overriding will work properly.

Comment: In order to deal with any other potential overriden that occurs previously i can replace the data=this.get("content") by data=this._super() :)

Comment: Oki got it work, you put me on the path  : http://jsbin.com/foyanupozi/5/edit?html,js,output , and i can work with the native {{each}} itemcontroller and so on which keeps the advantage of using ArrayController over default Controller.

Comment: I finally validate this solution (i thoug i did it before ... sorry)  as it put me on the path i adopted later on, see my previous comment for a bin :)